# How to separate data from a Json file to get separate Checkboxes next to them

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, checkbox, react-native-flatlist

I got my data from a fetched Json. ANd put them into a Flatlist and inside a the CHeckbox component to get checkboxes next to each item so you can separately check them. But after seeing the demo the data is all clumped together next to 1 checkbox you can check. How can i make sure the data is in a array and have all separate checkboxes

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from 'native-base';
const GLOBAL = require('../../assets/Globals');
const lessondata = ("../../assets/json/" + global.currentLesson + ".json");

export default class App extends Component {
  state={
    selectedLang1:false,

  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ data: json.movies });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }

  // renderSeparatorView = () => {
  //   return (
  //     <View style={{
  //         height: 1, 
  //         width: "100%",
  //         backgroundColor: "#CEDCCE",
  //       }}
  //     />
  //   );
  // };

  render() {
    const { data, isLoading, selectedLang1 } = this.state;

    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.item}>
      <CheckBox checked={selectedLang1} color="#fc5185" onPress={()=>this.setState({selectedLang1:!selectedLang1})}/>
        {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
            <FlatList
            data={data}
            // ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparatorView}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (       
               <Text style={ 
                {...styles.checkBoxTxt,
                  color:this.state.selectedLang1?"#fc5185":"gray",
                  fontWeight:this.state.selectedLang1? "bold" :"normal"
                }}>{item.title}</Text>
            )}
            />
        )}
      </View>
          <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={(data) => navigate('Screen2')}
            style={styles.submit}>
            <Text style={{color:"white"}}>SUBMIT</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share the UI

Comment: Shared it with a gif also

Answer (score 0):

If you want checkboxes for every movie you need to move  your

```
<CheckBox checked={selectedLang1} color="#fc5185" onPress={()=>this.setState({selectedLang1:!selectedLang1})}/>
```

inside `renderItem`. So your renderItem should look something like this

```
renderItem={({ item }) => (
           <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>       
             <Text style={ 
              {...styles.checkBoxTxt,
                color:this.state.selectedLang1?"#fc5185":"gray",
                fontWeight:this.state.selectedLang1? "bold" :"normal"
              }}>{item.title}</Text>
             <CheckBox checked={item.checked} color="#fc5185" onPress={()=>this.setState({selectedLang1:!item.checked})}/>
           </View>
        )}
```

Comment: This is almost it but when checking one item all the items get checked at the same time now

Comment: You will need to have checked logic for each item instead of having only one checked state. Store an array of title and checked, like [{title: "Title", checked: false}, ...] and update the checked for required item on your onPress logic for checkbox